# Can I replace the power cord on an old electric drier, to fit my outlet?

Tags: electrical

I just purchased a used dryer and the pigtail is different can I still use it if I can get it to fit, I know this sounds strange but when your on a budget do what I got to do with in reason...

Comment: Do you mean that the cord does not fit in the receptacle (3 prong vs. 4 prong)?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the cord has too many, or not enough prongs to fit in the receptacle.  You can buy the appropriate cord at any big box home improvement, hardware, or online store.

Once you have the cord, search the internet for the manufacturer's documentation for the appliance.  Then follow the instructions for how to connect the new cord to the appliance.